# if/elseif and switch statements doesn't work properly in smarty 3

Tags: html, templates, smarty, smarty3

I use smarty templaates engines. I'm in this situation:

```
{extends file="base.tpl"}
    {if $title_block=="something"}
        {block name="button_blocco_1"} class="active"{/block}
    {elseif $title_block=="somethingelse"}
        {block name="button_blocco_2"} class="active"{/block}
    {elseif $title_block=="someother"}
        {block name="button_blocco_3"} class="active"{/block}
    {/if}
    {block name="content"}
        {* BODY OF THE PAGE HERE *}
    {/block}
{/extends}
```

This doesn't work because when I load the page all the tree buttons are active. So I tryed to install a switch plugin (Jeremy Pyne's one) and change my code in this way:

```
{extends file="base.tpl"}
    {switch var=$title_block}
        {case value="sonething" break}
            {block name="button_blocco_1"} class="active"{/block}
        {case value="somethingelse" break}
            {block name="button_blocco_2"} class="active"{/block}
        {case value="someother" break}
            {block name="button_blocco_3"} class="active"{/block}
    {/switch}
    {block name="content"}
        {* BODY OF THE PAGE HERE *}
    {/block}
{/extends}
```

but this produces exactly the same result.
Some hints and/or workarounds? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this perhaps a problem related to the blocks rather than the conditions? Does it behave correctly if you put a piece of text instead of the block tags?

Comment: @Synchro Yes, it is; if I put some text instead of blocs all works perfectly both with if statement and switch statement, by the way I need to set only one block at a time according to the $title_block variable. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of using blocks, set a variable and check it with an `if` in your template to mark the active one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of Smarty 3 you will notice:

> Template inheritance is a compile time process which creates a single
>   compiled template file. Compared to corresponding solutions based on
>   subtemplates included with the {include} tag it does have much better
>   performance when rendering.

so Smarty doesn't check anything else just compile `{block}` and that's it. That's why even if you put `{block}` inside any conditions it won't change anything.

Workaround for this would be removing blocks from child theme and using in `base.tpl` simply:

```
<button {if $title_block eq 'something'}class="active"{/if}>test button</button>
<button {if $title_block eq 'somethingelse'}class="active"{/if}>test button2</button>
<button {if $title_block eq 'someother'}class="active"{/if}>test button3</button>
```

The other solution (a bit cleaner) would be using `include` and passing value you want to compare. In `base.tpl` file you could place:

```
<button {include 'active.tpl' compare="something"}>test button</button>
<button {include 'active.tpl' compare="somethingelse"}>test button2</button>
<button {include 'active.tpl' compare="someother"}>test button3</button>
```

and in `active.tpl` file:

```
{if $title_block eq $compare} class="active" {/if}
```